# JQuery with WPF? Possible as on Adobe AIR?

Tags: jquery, wpf

From what I understand about Adobe AIR, you can use Javascript/HTML to develop desktop applications.

Does WPF also allow the use of Javascript/JQuery to build controls? Or is Microsoft's solution for interactivity here solely XAML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WPF is solely a desktop technology. even when writing an xbap in wpf the browser is just a container.

Comment: It would seem likely and useful that there would be some kind of tunnel to Javascript/HTML functionality available in XBAP applications, is there not or not one planned? WPF has the Page concept but it seems to be 100% XAML.

Comment: As Blounty says, this is not possible, WPF is just hosted inside a container.

Comment: also if you want that sort of functionality, there is always silverlight.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight is your answer.  Blounty is right, I don't beleive at this time you would be able to easily use Javascript/JQuery with WPF to develop custom controls.  He also in his comment mentions using Silverlight.

Here is a link to a blog entry with sample code: [JQuery with Silverlight](http://www.cynotwhynot.com/blog/post/Fun-with-Silverlight-and-jQuery.aspx)